# Why can random variables be used to model?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have been looking at some of my probability theory notes and found the following concept, illustrated by a simple example. I will act as if I have never seen this material before for the sake of asking this question, since the question arose when questioning intuition. If $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a probability space, that is, $\Omega$ is a set, $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ and $P$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{A}$. Furthermore assume that $(\Omega',\mathcal{A}')$ is another pair consisting of a space and a $\sigma$-algebra on that space. Then, if $X:\Omega \to \Omega'$ is a random variable, it suffices to know the distribution of $X$ in order to calculate probabilites of events of the form $\{X \in A\}$, where $A \in \mathcal{A}'$. A simple example is rolling a die once and calculating the probability of rolling an even number, that is, assume that $X$ is a laplace distributed random variable mapping to $\{1,...,6\}$ and define $A:=\{X \in \{2,4,6\}\}$. We can then compute $P^X(A)=\frac{1}{2}$, where $P^X$ denotes the push forward measure of $X$ (or distribution of $X$).

So what did we do here? We assumed to have a random variable $X$ that has a given distribution and has a given codomain. It is obvious that such an $X$ exists, since one can just choose $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)=(\Omega',\mathcal{A}',Q)$, where $Q$ denotes the laplace measure and define $X$ to be the identity on $\Omega$. However, why should this represent our experiment? I know that random variables are always used to do this sort of stuff, and I have also always used them, but when questioning this now, I actually wondered why experiments can be represented by random variables. The naive way that is intuitive to me would be to define the laplace measure $P$ on $(\Omega',\mathcal{A}')$ and calculate $P(A).$ We then have a model to calculate the probability of $A$ by simply "measuring" $A$ in the intuitive space.

$(1)$ Why should this **always** be the same as when using a random variable? The use of random variables isn't directly connected to computing probabilites in a naive setting, I would say.

$(2)$ Furthermore, why should the push forward measure be the appropriate measure to **always** give the relevant probability? Technically speaking this is a "transformed calculation", why should this be the appropriate measure?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're asking, but I've always justified with the following observation: a random variable $X$ is a formalism representing the idea that we can (usually only) observe features of an outcome - so that we need not worry about the unseen mechanisms of $\Omega$. E.g. the temperature distribution on a rod - the mechanism by which each particle gains its kinetic energy at any time point is far too complex, but nonetheless that is an outcome or state "probability" space $\Omega$, but we just want to model the observables

Comment: The probability of the temperature of an area of the rod being $t$ degrees cannot really be modelled by "measuring $A$ in the intuitive space"; at least, I don't see how that would work. It definitely can however be modelled as an observable feature (random variable) of a complex random-appearing probability space (the positions and kinetic energies of the rod's particles)